# How do I store the result from reading a text file as a variable?

Tags: python

I'm trying to read from a text document

```
text_file.readline(2)
```

Any ideas how I could save the result under a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
variable = text_file.readline(2)
```

Perhaps you should read a basic tutorial :).

Comment: I did this, my variable just grays out and displays as not in use when I call it later in the program.

Comment: @Jamie, I'm not sure what you mean; you should ask a new question about that. Feel free to post a link to it here.